# How to mock routes inside the Multicast in Apache Camel Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

How to mock routes inside the Multicast in Apache Camel Test

I am getting an error when mocking the routes inside the multicast in Cameltest, I probably missed something or I incorrectly doing this

Please see code snippet below:

```
// RouteBuilder class
from(direct("get-data-id"))
    .routeId("direct:get-data-id")
    .setProperty("id", simple("${headers.id}"))
    .multicast(new ImplAggregationStrategy()).parallelProcessing()
        .to(direct("get-data-service-route"))
    .end()
    .setBody(DatasonnetExpression.builder("payload", String.class)
        .bodyMediaType(MediaTypes.APPLICATION_JAVA)
        .outputMediaType(MediaTypes.APPLICATION_JSON))
;
```

```
// Camel Test
routeToTest = "direct:get-data-id";
RouteDefinition routeDefinition = context.getRouteDefinition(routeToTest);
AdviceWith.adviceWith(routeDefinition, context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        weaveByToString(".*get-data-service-route.*")
            .replace()
            .setBody(datasonnet("resource:classpath:/data/get-persons-personId-response.json", LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.class));

        weaveAddLast().to("mock:result");
    }
});
```

Error logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There are no outputs which matches: .*get-data-service-route.* in the route: Route(direct:get-data-id)[From[direct://get-data-id] -> [OnException[[com.ms3_inc.camel.extensions.rest.exception.RestException] -> [process[Processor@0x18ac53e8], SetBody[com.datasonnet.document.DefaultDocument@c3177d5], 
.
.
.
```

Comment: May be the minus sign (-) needs to be escaped in the regex passed in param of weaveByToString ?

Comment: hmmm, @TacheDeChoco i have a similar mocking of those routes and its all working but only this inside the multicast cannot be mocked

Comment: Try to change `.to( direct("get-data-service-route") )` with `.to("direct:get-data-service-route")`

Comment: I just tried it now @TacheDeChoco but i got the same error